# Unselectable Ajax Content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div, and I'm reloading it with Ajax every 1 second. And it has auto value as overflow. To keep my div always bottom, I'm using a javascript code in Ajax request.

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    document.getElementById('chatting').scrollTop = 9999999;
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        document.getElementById('chatting').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()',1000);
    }
}
var withdate=document.getElementById('firstdate').value;
nocache = Math.random();
xmlHttp.open("GET","db.getMessages.php?date=" + withdate + "&nocache = "+nocache,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout('Ajax()',1000);
}
```

But I can't select texts and can't go upper. When the new content is loaded, div slides bottom. How can I solve this?

---

I've a question too. I'm using a PHP file to define json contents. And output is like this:

```
{ "msg": [{"from":"demo","text":"test message "} ] }
```

But Firebug shows this error to me:

Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character
Source File: http://localhost/script/script/json.js
Line: 20

Line 20 is:

> var msgs = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

I struggle so much but haven't solve :(

Comment: It doesn't look too much "jQuery"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replace the whole chatting-Element and expect the browser to remember and keep the selection? 
I guess you're implementing a simple chat client, right? Then, why don't you just pull **new** messages instead of, I guess, all? Return all messages as JSON and create DOM-nodes on your own which you **append** to the chatting-element. That approach allows you to select content as it never changes and keeps traffic down.

btw:
nocache-Parameters are usually done using a timestamp, because time is always increasing. A Math.random() is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I'm not good at javascript programming, can you show an example please?

Comment: There you go: http://pastebin.com/3sA3CBYF
I did some more changes on the code so I can run it without having a Messages.php. But in the end this will work out.

Comment: I've a question too. I'm using a PHP file to define json contents. And output is like this:

{ "msg": [{"from":"demo","text":"test message "} ] }

But Firebug shows this error to me:

Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character Source File: http://localhost/script/script/json.js Line: 20

Line 20 is:

    var msgs = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

I struggle so much but haven't solve :(